How to Bind SfTreeGrid ExpanderContextMenu MenuItem Command to ViewModel Command Using Dependency Injection
I am working with Syncfusion's SfTreeGrid in a WPF application and using dependency injection (DI) to manage my view models. My goal is to bind a MenuItem in the SfTreeGrid.ExpanderContextMenu to a command (ExpandCommand) in my view model, ViewModel. Here’s a summary of my setup:
ViewModel:

I have a ViewModel registered as a singleton with DI.
ExpandCommand is a public ICommand in ViewModel.

Dependency Injection:
ViewModel is registered as a singleton:
services.AddSingleton<ViewModel>();

DataContext:
At the page level, I set DataContext to an instance of ViewModel:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.ServiceProvider.GetService<ViewModel>();
    }
}
X

AML Binding:
I tried binding ExpandCommand in the ExpanderContextMenu using RelativeSource and PlacementTarget, but it doesn’t seem to work.
Here’s the code that isn’t working as expected:
<syncfusion:SfTreeGrid x:Name="treeGrid">
    <syncfusion:SfTreeGrid.ExpanderContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem
                Command="{Binding DataContext.ExpandCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Header="Expand" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </syncfusion:SfTreeGrid.ExpanderContextMenu>
</syncfusion:SfTreeGrid>

Issue:
The Command binding for ExpandCommand in ViewModel is not working. It seems that the ContextMenu does not inherit the DataContext as expected, and binding with RelativeSource or PlacementTarget hasn’t resolved the issue.
What I’ve Tried:

Setting DataContext for SfTreeGrid directly to ViewModel.
Using PlacementTarget.DataContext.ExpandCommand with RelativeSource.
Adding ViewModel to resources as a static resource and binding with {StaticResource}, but this conflicts with my DI setup, as I cannot define it as a resource in XAML.

Question:
What is the correct way to bind the MenuItem in SfTreeGrid.ExpanderContextMenu to a command in my ViewModel, while using dependency injection to manage the view model? Any guidance or alternative approaches would be appreciated.
